# Grabbing A WordPress Post's Image and Displaying it?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to grab a post's first image and have it displayed as a thumbnail link to the post itself on the homepage? I can't seem to figure it out. Prefer not to use the featured image function. Is there a workaround? Any help would be much appreciated.

---

Would I be able to use the following code to acheive what I want? It doesn't seem like I can specify a post ID, but maybe i'm wrong?

http://www.wordimpressed.com/wordpress/get-the-first-image-from-a-post-and-display-it/

My main concern is grabbing a few posts and being able to display them on the frontpage/homepage. Is that possible?

Comment: Would RegExp allow me to grab only from a few posts? Could I specify a post id in the parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it through two ways:

```
function post_photo_count_attachments( $post_id ) {

    $attachments = get_children(
        array( 'post_parent' => $post_id ) 
    );

    return( $attachments[0] );
```

}

Or by Query/XPath method:

```
function post_photo_count_xpath( $post_id ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $post_id_safe = intval( $post_id );

    $html = $wpdb->get_row(
        "select * from {$wpdb->posts} where ID={$post_id_safe} limit 1"
    );

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML( $html->post_content );
    $path = new DOMXpath( $doc );
    $images = $path->query( "//img" );

    return( $images->item(0)->getAttribute('src') );
}
```

print_r() these returns for more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

I've a code similar working in my web in the loop. It should work fine for you!

```
        $content = $post->post_content;
    $content = preg_replace('/\[.*\]/', '', $content);
    $image = '';
    $x = stripos($content, '<img');
    if ($x !== false) {
        $x = stripos($content, 'src="', $x);
        if ($x !== false) {
            $x += 5;
            $y = strpos($content, '"', $x);
            $image = substr($content, $x, $y-$x);
        }
    }
```

It works fine for me, so if you've problems please tell me. ;)

Comment: Thanks. How would I be able to use this code to fetch an image from a post. Say the post ID is 3234...would I be able to use that ID and make an image appear on the front page?

Comment: Easy!

$my_id = 3234;
$post = get_post($my_id);